# How to show tags data in TFS-VSTS (Team foundation server) chart?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

we are using tags on work items on TFS, and while we can use it on the queries (field tags == 'something') we can not use it on charts, when we try to make a chart from the query the field tags doesn't appears on the select options. We would like to do a stacked chart based on tags field.

Answer (score 0):

Query chart works for a flat list query, but not a tree query or a direct links query. And for the queries, it's impossible to group by **tags**. The featrue is unavailable at present.

There's already a [**user voice here**](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/6559309-allow-team-web-access-charts-to-group-by-tags) to suggest the feature, you can go and vote it up to achieve that in future.

Comment: @Luis Molina Is the answer helpful for you? any update?